# How can I automate or script daily downloads for any new anti- virus databases, and then have the program scan my drive?

Tags: macos, bash, script, cron, crontab

(I know there are much better softwares out there for the Mac so please don't go there! The politics of this company dictate which Anti virus we have to use)

Anyway without any further wait:

Basically I am trying to automate 2 very important functions of McAfee anti-virus for Mac. First I want to automate the process of retrieving new virus definition files, and second I want to automate the process of scanning for viruses. It turns out that Using Mc'Afee Anti-Virus for the Mac are both manual functions. And they left up to the user (per user account) to perform. Depending on all of about 150 Mac users to perform these 2 tasks themselves is around 65% compliance.

My question then is: 
If I wanted to use the command line such as (`open /Applications/McAfee\ Security.App`) It will open up the Security Console. But how can I make command McAfee go out and grab the definition files and scan the computer?
I have to admit I am at a crossroad and Macaltimers has set in.

Comment: Computer Wizards don't grow old, they just lose their Memory

Comment: what are the target computers? Are they remaining where they are (as opposed to notebooks users just take with them when they leave), and at what times does the OS run (all day? office hours?)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual here](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/20000/PD20668/en_US/VirusScan_for_Mac_8.6_User_Guide.pdf):

> To schedule scans, open the application in /Applications/Utilities/VirusScan Schedule Editor.app

You can always try using Automator workflows to manipulate GUIs. I'd create two workflows, one to press the 'Update Now' button and a second to press the 'Scan' button.

1. Open Automator and choose to create an application
2. Build a workflows like this:

   1. Launch Application (McAfee Virus Scanner)
   2. Use the 'Record' button in the top-right corner or the 'Watch Me Do' action to record GUI activity
3. After you've saved and built both applications, you can use them in shell scripts as warranted to automate the GUI.